# how to make copies of Cython objects?

Tags: python, c, cython

I have a simple Cython class where I define what it means to compare two objects for equality (`==`):

```
cdef class MyClass:
  cdef public int a
  cdef public int b
  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b

  def __richcmp__(self, MyClass other, int op):
    if op == 2:
      if (self.a == other.a) and (self.b == other.b):
        return True
      return False
    raise Exception, "No other op"
```

If I make an instance of MyClass in Python and then copy it, it breaks the object:

```
import copy
myobj = MyClass(5, 10)
myobj_copy = copy.copy(myobj)
# myobj_copy is now defective
# ..
```

what is the correct way to create copies of instances of Cython classes? I want to make a copy and then modify it without affecting the original object. **update** to be clear, MyClass also inherits from another Cython (`cdef`) class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define a `__copy__` method for your class. Adding eg.

```
def __copy__(self):
    return MyClass(self.a, self.b)
```

to your code gives:

```
>>> import cp
>>> foo = cp.MyClass(5, 10)
>>> import copy
>>> bar = copy.copy(foo)
>>> bar == foo
True
```

As an alternative, if you want also to pickle your object you may want to implement [The pickle protocol for extension type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-extension-types) that is a `__reduce__` method. Then it will be used for copying.

Comment: Do you mean ``import copy as cp``?

Comment: @user248237dfsf : non ! I wrote your code under the name `cp.pyx`, compiled it into `cp.so` therefore I import it using `import cp`.